# BigQuery : Bulk update Table using DML queries

Tags: google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I'm using `query` API from `com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery` to perform update operations [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-update-with-dml).

Is there a way to perform bulk update to BigQuery Table similar to `insertAll` or `writeJsonStream`.

Comment: The best alternative that I can think of is to use a `for loop`.

Comment: @ScottB, you mean to keep calling BigQuery::query() in a loop. ok. I will do that till I find a better alternative. Thanks.

Comment: Yes correct. I will post my post as answer, you may upvote it if you think it is a helpful workaround.

Comment: @ScottB, this is not what I was looking for. As I'm doing it in for loop. I was looking for one API which will connect once and perform all the operations on the server side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try and consider as a workaround wherein you will use a `for loop` to loop into your `query()` until all your needed update have been successfully executed.